# Have Bluetooth socket reconnect (in Python) after BT switched off and on again

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth

I connect a bluetooth device in a python (3.10) program like this:

```
import socket
serverMACAddress = '00:07:80:e0:a4:fc'
port = 1
size = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.connect((serverMACAddress,port))
```

In the main loop I have this:

```
try:
    while 1: #main loop
        data = s.recv(size)
        if data:
            data_received( data )
        else:
            try:
                s.???? 
            except: 
                print("no data") 
except: 
    print("Closing socket")
    s.close()
```

Everything works fine unless the bluetooth device is switched off and then switched on again. I am trying to solve how to have the bluetooth device re-connect with the logic in the try-statement (s.????) within the loop, but I am unable to come up with a solution.

I am a beginner in BT and Python, but this should be pretty straightforward, right? I must be missing something very obvious. Any suggestions out there?

Modified version based on the suggestion by ukBaz:

```
try:
    while 1: #main loop
        try:
            data = s.recv(size)
        except socket.error():
            connected = False
            s = socket.socket
            while not connected:
                #attempt to re-connect
                try:
                    s.connect((serverMACAddress,port))
                    connected = True
                except:
                    time.sleep(5)
        if data:
            data_received( data )
except: 
    print("Closing socket")
    s.close()
```

After adding clientSocket.send:

```
while True: #main loop
    # attempt to reconnect, otherwise sleep for 2 seconds
    if not connected:
        try:
            # configure socket and connect to server
            clientSocket = socket.socket(
                socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM
            )

            clientSocket.connect((serverMACAddress, port))
            connected = True
            print("Connection successful")
        except socket.error:
            print("No connection, retrying")
#            time.sleep(2)
    # attempt to send and receive, otherwise reset connection status
    else:
        data = clientSocket.recv(size)
        if data:
            data_received( data )
        # Use send to check if scale is connected
        try:
            clientSocket.send(b"x")
        except socket.error:
            print("connection lost... reconnecting")
            # set connection status
            connected = False
```

Comment: The client at the link below should be a good basis. Need to change the socket to be Bluetooth socket https://instructobit.com/tutorial/101/Reconnect-a-Python-socket-after-it-has-lost-its-connection#Full-example

Comment: @ukBaz The code in the link you provided seemed to be spot-on what I need - thanx! - but it does not work for me :-(   The exception handling after `except socket.error():` is never invoked.

Comment: Isn't it `except socket.error` not `except socket.error()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the following connecting to a remote HC-06 module on an Arduino. I tested the code below with Python 3.10 (Windows) and Python 3.8 (Linux) and it worked as expected on both.

It has a continuous while loop that if it is connected sends & receives data. If it is not connected, then it tries to connect. It uses `except socket.error` to detect there is an issue with the connection.

```py
import socket
from time import sleep

host = "00:00:12:34:56:78"
port = 1
chunks = 1024

# keep track of connection status
connected = False

while True:
    # attempt to reconnect, otherwise sleep for 2 seconds
    if not connected:
        try:
            # configure socket and connect to server
            clientSocket = socket.socket(
                socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM
            )

            clientSocket.connect((host, port))
            connected = True
            print("Connection successful")
        except socket.error:
            print("No connection, retrying")
            sleep(2)
    # attempt to send and receive, otherwise reset connection status
    else:
        try:
            print("sending data...")
            clientSocket.send(b"Test")
            print("Reading data..")
            message = clientSocket.recv(chunks).decode("UTF-8")
            print("Recv'd", message)
        except socket.error:
            # set connection status
            connected = False
            print("connection lost... reconnecting")
```

If the socket is only doing read, then a timeout needs to be set so that it raises an exception. The value of the timeout might need to be tuned for your particular situation. As an example:

```py
import socket
import time

import select

serverMACAddress = "00:00:12:34:56:78"
port = 1
size = 1024

# keep track of connection status
connected = False


def data_received(info):
    print(info)


while True: #main loop
    # attempt to reconnect, otherwise sleep for 2 seconds
    if not connected:
        try:
            # configure socket and connect to server
            clientSocket = socket.socket(
                socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM
            )

            clientSocket.connect((serverMACAddress, port))
            clientSocket.settimeout(5.5)
            connected = True
            print("Connection successful")
        except socket.error:
            print("No connection, retrying")
            time.sleep(2)
    # attempt to send and receive, otherwise reset connection status
    else:
        try:
            data = clientSocket.recv(size)
            print("Reading data..")
            if data:
                data_received(data)
        # Assume connection lost if read timeout raised
        except socket.timeout:
            # set connection status
            connected = False
            print("connection lost... reconnecting")
```

Comment: I modified my code according to your proposal and the problem remains: when the BT device is switched OFF the code does not produce an exception 'socket.error'. The code keeps on running ... print("Reading data.."). If I restart the program it connects to the BT device and everything works fine until the BT device is switched OFF/ON. Note: switching OFF the device does indeed really disconnect it to some degree, because after switching it ON again the program does not register the data being received from the BT device.

Comment: If you update your question with your new code I can give it a try to see if I can reproduce the problem

Comment: I added the latest version to your answer section ... please let me know if I ought to move it to the section of my question.

Comment: If a `settimeout` is added to the socket when it is just reading then the exception is raised. I've used `socket.timeout` but you can use the more generic `socket.error`.

Comment: I have finally gotten around to trying out your latest answer. I concluded that it has a significant drawback: the timeout causes a disconnect which means that the BT device is not ready to use for a few seconds. In order for the device to be usable in an uninterrupted manner I found this solution not usable. Instead I just implemented `try:
clientSocket.send(b"x")         except socket.error:` which throws an error (as required) when the BT device is not connected (I have added the modified code snippet above).

Comment: I do have a question on this however: it takes about 15 seconds after the BT device is disconnected (i.e. reaching the statement `print("connection lost... reconnecting")`). This long time is quite inconvenient. The re-connecting itself goes very quick. You have any ideas/suggestions how to remedy this?

Comment: @mortpiedra if you set `clientSocket.settimeout` that should bring it down from 15 seconds.