# bluetooth module blocking the rest of the program in case of connection reset or host is down

Tags: python, multithreading, bluetooth

I am trying to send and receive data simultaneously using bluetooth between client and server sides. The scripts are separate and running on separate devices, on for client and one for server. Initially, the rest of my programs would get blocked in a loop if there was a connection reset or issue with the client or server connection. So I added a single thread in both codes. Now it seems to fix the issue but I am not sure whether it's the correct way to solve this problem.

I have the following codes for client and server sides.

client side:

```
import bluetooth
import threading

# Set the server's Bluetooth address and port number
bd_addr = "00:e0:4c:9a:f8:64"
port = 1


def client():
    while True:
        try:
            # Create a Bluetooth socket and connect to the server
            sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
            sock.connect((bd_addr, port))

            # Continuously receive data from the server and print it out
            while True:
                data = sock.recv(1024)
                print("Received from server:", data.decode())

                # Prompt the user to type something to send back to the server
                txt = input("Type something to send back to the server: ")
                sock.send(txt.encode())

        except Exception as e:
            # If an error occurs, print the error message and close the socket
            # print(e)
            sock.close()

# Start the receive_data and send_data functions in separate threads
threading.Thread(target=client).start()
```

server side:

```
import bluetooth
import threading

def server():
    while True:
        try:
            # Create a Bluetooth socket and bind it to the specified port
            server_sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
            port = 1
            server_sock.bind(("", port))
            server_sock.listen(1)

            # Accept an incoming connection from a client
            client_sock, address = server_sock.accept()
            print("Accepted connection from", address)

            # Continuously prompt the user to type something to send to the client
            while True:
                txt = input("Type something to send to the client: ")
                client_sock.send(txt.encode())

                # Receive data from the client and print it out
                data = client_sock.recv(1024)
                print("Received from client:", data.decode())

        except Exception as e:
            # If an error occurs, print the error message and close the sockets
            # print(e)
            client_sock.close()
            server_sock.close()

# Start the receive_data and send_data functions in separate threads
threading.Thread(target=server).start()
```

Is using threading this way, to prevent the rest of the program in each script getting stuck, in case of connection error on either side, correct?

Are there any other/better ways to fix the issue, such as callback function?

Comment: Assuming these are part of the same application, then that's a reasonable enough approach.  If they are separate processes, then the threading is unnecessary.

Comment: @TimRoberts, they are two separate scripts running on two separate devices. Without threading if there is an error on either side of the connection, won't the rest of the program get stuck in loop?

Comment: Are the programs doing anything else?  If that's all there is, then who cares if it gets blocked?

Comment: Yes. the programs will be used for IOT applications. For example, sending/receiving sensor data, object recognition/audio recognition data.

Comment: from https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html `"if a socket send or recv returns after handling 0 bytes, the connection has been broken. If the connection has not been broken, you may wait on a recv forever, because the socket will not tell you that there’s nothing more to read"` You mask that problem by putting the code in a thread. A better method is to detect the lost of connection and re-establish the connection. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71950023/7721752